# onClick function not working in android studio

Tags: android

I was trying to make a timer app and I came across a hurdle. When I try to click the button its not performing its task. The onClick function seems to go wrong somewhere.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        SeekBar timerSeekBar;
        TextView timerTextView;
        public void updateTimer(int secondsLeft){

            int minutes = (int) secondsLeft / 60;
            int seconds = secondsLeft - minutes * 60;




            timerTextView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds));

        }


        public void controlTimer(View view){

            Log.i("Work","Yes");

          /*  new CountDownTimer(timerSeekBar.getProgress() * 1000, 1000){

               @Override
               public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                   updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);

               }

               @Override
               public void onFinish() {
                   Log.i("Finished", "Done");
               }
           }.start();
    */

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            timerSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);
            timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);



            timerSeekBar.setMax(600);
            timerSeekBar.setProgress(30);


            timerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    updateTimer(progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timerSeekBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/egg"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerSeekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0:30"
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:onClick="controlTimer" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO!"
        android:id="@+id/controllerButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
07-02 13:11:32.074 1999-1999/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17962: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17966: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
07-02 13:11:32.170 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-02 13:11:32.250 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-02 13:11:32.278 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 7% free 3355K/3608K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
07-02 13:11:32.278 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.590MB for 2349444-byte allocation
07-02 13:11:32.286 1999-2008/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 5645K/5904K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
07-02 13:11:32.426 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
07-02 13:11:32.454 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
07-02 13:11:32.458 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
07-02 13:11:32.502 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-02 13:11:32.506 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
07-02 13:11:32.506 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
07-02 13:11:32.510 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
07-02 13:11:32.514 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
07-02 13:11:32.514 1999-1999/toast.akappstudio.com.eggtimer D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

After this point when I try to run the app in the emulator and click on the go button it does not display anything in the log cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the event handler on `TextView` not on `Button`.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0:30"
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:onClick="controlTimer" />
```

Set it on your `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any click listener to your button in your code or have you not included the code for that in your code for brevity? However if that is not the case then you can set click listener on your button by two ways in your activity:

**Method 1**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ......

   Button controllerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controllerButton);
   controllerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code you want to execute on click of a button
        }
    });
}
```

**Method 2**

**content.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO!"
    android:id="@+id/controllerButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timerTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   switch(view.getId()) {
      case R.id.controllerButton:
           //Code you want to execute on click of a button
           break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is your button code. As long as you have create a button in xml layout without `android:onClick=""`, you won't be able to use the onClick(View) inside your java file. However, you can still make it work by replacing your `controlTimer(View)` method with below snippet:

```
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.controlTimer);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

new CountDownTimer(timerSeekBar.getProgress() * 1000, 1000){

           @Override
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

               updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);

           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               Log.i("Finished", "Done");
           }
       }.start();
});
```